# Adjustable textinput in kivy scrollview

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to Kivy. I would like multiple textInputs to be displayed properly inside the Kivy scrollView dynamically where the textInput size fits the content. The current code displays only 3 as the height of the gridLayout is set to 1000. I would like to use height: self.minimum_height so that I can dynamically add more textInputs and they will be displayed properly, however but cannot seem to get it working.

My kv file:

```
<MyNote@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    TextInput:
        height: self.minimum_height
        multiline: True
        text_size: self.size
        size_hint_y: None
        text: '1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14\n15'

<MainNotesBoxLayout>
    orientation: 'vertical'

    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None

            height: 1000
            #height: self.minimum_height

            MyNote:
            MyNote:
            MyNote:
```

My main file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MainNotesBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class NotesApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainNotesBoxLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NotesApp().run()
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you provide better description or some screenshots of what would you like to achieve, and what do you currently have?

Comment: Sure, I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Replace GridLayout with BoxLayout
2. Set the minimum height of the boxlayout so that there is something to scroll.

[ScrollView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html)

> layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

## Example

### notes.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MyNote(TextInput):
    pass


class MainNotesBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    container = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainNotesBoxLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.container.bind(minimum_height=self.container.setter('height'))
        self.add_text_inputs()

    def add_text_inputs(self):
        for x in range(100):
            my_note = MyNote()
            self.container.add_widget(my_note)


class NotesApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainNotesBoxLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    NotesApp().run()
```

### notes.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MyNote>:
    height: self.minimum_height
    multiline: True
    text_size: self.size
    size_hint_y: None
    text: '1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14\n15'

<MainNotesBoxLayout>
    container: container
    orientation: 'vertical'

    ScrollView:
        size_hint: (1, 1)
        bar_width: 10
        bar_color: 1, 0, 0, 1   # red
        bar_inactive_color: 0, 0, 1, 1   # blue
        effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
        scroll_type: ['bars']


        BoxLayout:
            id: container
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1, None
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Scrolling]